# Does image file type matter in terms of accuracy or speed when training/evaluating in machine learning?

Tags: image, tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, keras

I would like to know if the image file type matters at all in image classification using Keras, Tensorflow, or any other machine learning library. For example:

If I were to train using only JPG files, will the accuracy be significantly affected if I were to evaluate the model using only PNG files?

If so, will it be better to train using both JPG and PNG files so I can evaluate using both types?

Or does the image file type not matter at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file type does not matter.

During training (and inference for that matter) images are converted into a tensors (you can think of this just as a multi dimensional array) where each pixel is represented by a small group of numbers (or a single number for black and white images).

Machine learning is performed on these *tensors* rather than the image itself so the original file format really doesn't matter.